# Sum last 12 months data when there is no data for few months in between

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

Trying to sum data for the past 12 months, but there are few months with no data so the month name is completely missing from the dataset:

How do I calculate last 12 months data between jan 2019 and jan 2020 considering missing months data as 0?

[image]

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: Why is a column named "Date" a string? And even worse why does it have data other than dates? That is a huge design issue.

Comment: Yes I know. The purpose of date field is to label the totals on the dataset such as last year total, current year total, YTD etc., We have a requirement to show the trend last 3, 6 and 12 months now using this table. All we have is month nos and year to do it

Comment: Can you show us the output you desire?  Sorry, I've read your question a few times and I'm not sure if you are trying to figure out how to specify a date range given your fractured representation of dates and years, if you are trying to show missing months (a gaps-and-islands problem) in the query results, or both.

Comment: Reasons not to use images are [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/92546).

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server you can use `apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.total1
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.total) as total1
      from t t2
      where t2.date <= t.date and
            t2.date > dateadd(month, -12, t.date)
     ) t2;
```

Because your date column is broken, you can instead use:

```
select t.*, t2.total1
from t outer apply
     (select sum(t2.total) as total1
      from t t2
      where t2.year * 12 + t2.month <= t.year * 12 + t.month and
            t2.year * 12 + t2.month > t.year * 12 + t.month - 12
     ) t2;
```

Comment: 'Date' Field is string, it has other texts in it as well. The only fields I can use to calculate this is 'Month' and 'Year'

Comment: @sql_dev1802 . . . Fix your data model!  And you should make your question clearer when you ask it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DATEFROMPARTS function to convert the month and year into a date:

```
select sum(total1) as total
from table
where datefromparts(year,month,1) between '01Jan2019' and '01Jan2020'
```

If you want a dynamic result for the last 12 months then:

```
select sum(total1) as total
from table
where datefromparts(year,month,1) between DATEADD(month,-13,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Hope this helps.